# Calling another script (here: Python) from a Powershell script with non-ASCII-chars in argument

Tags: powershell, batch-file, encoding, utf-8, codepages

I'm on Windows 10 with Powershell 5.1

`printargs.py` is:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

#### Case 1

I have a Windows batch file `runme.bat`:

```
chcp 65001
py printargs.py ä
```

Note: `py.exe` is the Python launcher for Windows

**This is working:** I invoke the batch file in a Powershell terminal and I get output

```
printargs.py
ä
```

#### Case 2

Now I want powershell script `runme.ps1` doing exactly the same thing:

```
# What code must go here?
& py printargs.py ä
```

**This is NOT working:** Because of some encoding problem I get

```
printargs.py
Ã¤
```

I' am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window).

I tried without success:

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Comment: Fix may be as simple as setting the localization correctly or doing something like r('a'), see details (article contain lots informative links), https://nick.groenen.me/posts/%C3%A4-and-%C3%A4-are-not-the-same-character/   and   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq

Comment: I don't think this behavior is related to Python.

Comment: Make the .ps1 file utf8withbom encoding.

Comment: @js2010 you're right, this solves the problem. As far as I get it, the BOM signals powershell that the ps1-file is UTF8-encoded. Is there no way to do this programatically and without adding the BOM? I'm a bit confused, could anybody elaborate on the topic or redirect me to a full answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes up a lot.  Powershell 5.1 can't read utf8 no bom.  This will covert the script to utf8 with bom.  Powershell 7 can handle utf8 no bom.

```
(get-content -encoding utf8 script.ps1) | set-content script.ps1 -encoding utf8


# bom tests
(get-content script.ps1 -AsByteStream)[0] -eq 0xef -and 
(get-content script.ps1 -AsByteStream)[1] -eq 0xbb

True


# right side gets converted to string
'239 187' -eq (get-content script.ps1 -AsByteStream)[0..1]

True
```

Comment: Probably the main takeaway from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.3): "If you need to use non-Ascii characters in your scripts, save them as UTF-8 with BOM. Without the BOM, Windows PowerShell misinterprets your script as being encoded in the legacy "ANSI" codepage."

Comment: On my system I got the following: If `in.ps1`  is encoded as utf8-without-bom *and* contains non-Ascii chars, then (**your code**)
`(get-content in.ps1) | set-content out.ps1 -encoding utf8`
produces a file `out.ps1` with utf8-with-bom encoding but also *messed up non-Ascii chars*.
On the other hand the non-Ascii chars are *handled correctly* with
`(get-content in.ps1 -encoding utf8) | set-content out.ps1 -encoding utf8`.

Comment: Correction made.